# Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

I understand that this is a typical error, but I cannoty figure out, where is the problem located? The link in browser opens normally with JSON structure, but in `weatherRequest.json()` i even got an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

Help, please...

```
let fetchWeather = async () => {
    const weatherRequest = await fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=my_key`);
    const weatherStore = await weatherRequest.json();
    console.log('weatherStore', weatherStore);
}

fetchWeather();
```

Comment: You have used bad quotes around string on line 2... Use ' (single quote) instead of ` (backtick)

Comment: @panther That makes no sense.

Comment: Is result of fetch correct JSON?

Comment: you need https in the url.

Comment: `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=my_key`  is a relative path, so the current domain will be added in front of it. Because of that you will request that path from your domain, wich would most likely return a html error page. And that error page starts with `<`.  You need to wirte `//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=my_key`, `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=my_key` or `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=my_key`

Comment: @t.niese than you that it!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't see how that's a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @melpomene Sorry then. Opening it.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. Two fixes helped me resolve this issue.

1. Used `axios` instead of `fetch`. (Not sure why fetch didn't help)

Install -> `npm install axios`

Use ->     `import axios from 'axios';`

2. Prefixed the api url with `https://` like this `https://api.openweathermap.org...`

[image]